# Spring - tag form:textarea must be empty, but is not error

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I want to get the value in a spring form based textarea using the jstl tag, like the code given below

How could I render this?

```
<form:textarea value="${u.content}" path="content">
</form:textarea>
```

I get the error "tag form:textarea must be empty, but is not" on running this view page

Answer (score 4):

If your form is bound to a commandName/modelAttribute you don't need the value attribute just the path is enough.
e.g.

if form is declared like below.

```
<form:form id="form" method="post" modelAttribute="formBean">
```

your text area needs to be just

```
<form:textarea  path="name"/>
```

where name is an attribute of formBean object

```
public class FormBean {     
    private String name = "name";
}
```

Pre Initialized values.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/personForm")
public String showForm(Model model) {
    //read values from db and add it as model .e.g. 
    Person person = new Person();
    model.addAttribute("person", person);
    return "personForm";
}
```

jsp:

```
<form:form action="/personForm" commandName="person" method="post">         
   Name1: <form:textarea path="name"/>
</form:form>
```

Comment: actually I am retrieving the form values from database using the mvc pattern and all that, and was using jstl tags to retrieve the values in the view from controller, so how would I do that? I have seven entities which I want to retrieved in the form & unable to get the value for the form:textarea

Comment: so add the bean object as model and then read the values. e.g. if you create content object having those seven attributes your form commandName would be content and textArea path would be the one attribute you want to map to.